# Undefined Subintervals - Riemann Integrals

Tags: integration

I searched through stackexchange and multiple other PDFs but couldn't find an answer

I'm curious to know when talking about Riemann Integrals with respect to functions that are bounded on closed bounded intervals (which we've been studying).

If I take some arbitrary function $f$ which is bounded on the interval $[a,b]$ (where a and b are finite real numbers); what happens if the function $f$ is undefined on a sub interval of a particular partition in that closed bounded interval $[a,b]$? This sub interval can't have a lub or a glb since the sub interval doesn't contain any real numbers (in this example). Is it just completely ignored in the sum since there is no "area"? Please explain

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, i'm not understanding your question correctly, but are you essentially asking if you have some function that is discontinuous in a partition how would you perform the Riemann Integral?  I would imagine that the best approach would be to break up your function into however many discontinuities that may exist on the partition and perform the the Riemann Integral on those sub partitions that exist and then add them up.

Comment: Yep, discontinuous. So you're saying that you ignore the subintervals in [a,b] where the function is discontinuous, and only sum the continuous subintervals (given some partition)? I don't really believe your answer, since the Riemann Sum is defined such that you're finding the glb or lub of a particular subinterval of [a,b] (depending on whether you're talking about lower or upper sums) which doesn't exist if the function is discontinuous (undefined) on the entire subinterval

Comment: I don't really see the problem.  If a function isn't defined on a certain sub-interval then how can you possibly find a glb or lub?  It's the same idea of breaking up an integral of a discontinuous function on an interval.

Comment: Exactly, you can't have a glb or lub, that's the problem. So given a partition, where the function is discontinuous over a single subinterval (for a given partition) is the sum still defined even though one of the terms in the sum doesn't have a glb or a lub?

Comment: The Riemann sum is only defined on the intervals where it is not discontinuous.  Thus if you want to take a Riemann sum over an entire interval and there exist discontinuous subintervals you have to break up the sum to not include those intervals.

Comment: Perfect, cheers for the reply man

Answer (score 0):

For Riemann integrability, you need the function to be bounded in the interval, and the set of discontinuities to have a Lebesgue measure of 0.

You can extend this to undefined points by saying that the undefined point could be any value without changing the value of the Riemann integral, so the value at that point doesn't matter.  This isn't the most rigorous thing you can say, but it can be said.

An entire sub-interval would have a Lebesgue measure greater than 0, because it would scale with the unit interval.

I wouldn't trust any definition of an integral that gives a value to a set with an undefined value.  I think it makes the most sense to say that an integral over an undefined interval is undefined.  Other than that, you might get away with calling it 0, or you might give it a value in a different unit that basically only gives you the measure of the undefined set under some obscure math.